# NuSMV on Mac -int command option not found

Tags: command-line, terminal, nusmv

I'm trying to run NuSMV on Mac and I can run it normally but when I need to use the interactive mode the -int option gets an error - The command line option "–int" is unknown.

Has anybody else had this issue?

Comment: Did you try `NuSMV -h` and check whether `-int` is among the listed options?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Yes -int is in the list

Comment: did you try some older / newer version of the tool? VirtualBox?